# How do you add a line break inside of a javascript variable using KineticJS?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
var simpleText = new Kinetic.Text({
    text: 'where text goes',
    fontSize: 24
  });
```

How do I insert a line break where the text goes. I've tried:

```
text: 'where text goes \n where text goes',

text: 'where text goes \n\n where text goes',

text: 'where text goes \r\n where text goes',

text: 'where text goes <br /> where text goes',

text: 'where text goes \n' + 'where text goes \n',

text: 'where text goes ' + 'where text goes ',

text: 'where text goes ' 
+ 'where text goes ',

text: 'where text goes 
where text goes',
```

**Error on my end. \n works**

Comment: It's probably outputting HTML, so use `<br />` instead of `\n`. Otherwise, your first example should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't work, it's not outputting html. Also when I use \n it doesn't output any text at all.

Comment: Are you using this library?: https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS

Comment: Yes I am using that @Ian

Comment: I have used `\n` in my work... so the error must be somewhere else. Try to set the breakpoints and dig in

Answer (score 9):

If you are outputting to HTML, such as with `innerHTML`, just use `<br />`.

If, however, you are outputting to text in an HTML context (such as `nodeValue` or `innerText`, you will have to use `\n` and ensure that the container has the CSS `white-space` property set to something that doesn't condence whitespace, such as `pre-wrap`.

Comment: \n doesn't work nor does <br />. Sorry I forgot to mention I'm using KineticJS.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of Kinetic text but based on this sample: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-text-tutorial/  you should do:

`text: 'where text goes\n\nwhere text goes',`

Comment: It doesn't say to use `\n\n`. It has that for **2** line breaks. Notice the extra line in the output...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately that doesn't work either. I will update my question.

Comment: Thanks @Ian I did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

Using html() instead of 'text' and 'val'

.html('using some -br- simple text here');

Result: using some
        simple text here